# Nested ng-repeat with JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a nested ng-repeat but can't quite figure out what's wrong. Nothing is printing in the nested ng-repeat

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons">
 <p> {{ person.name }} </p>
 <div ng-repeat="friend in person.mutual_friends">
   {{ friend.name }}
 </div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
$scope.persons = [
    {
      name: 'First Person',
      mutual_friends: [ 
        { 
          name: 'Mutual Friend 1' 
        }, 
        { 
          name: 'Mutual Friend 2' 
        }, 
      ]
    },
   {
      name: 'Second Person',
      mutual_friends: [ 
        { 
          name: 'Mutual Friend 1' 
        }, 
        { 
          name: 'Mutual Friend 2' 
        }, 
      ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.. Check your console for any errors that may have been logged, or probably the data structure is not exactly how you think it is.. Try to replicate this issue and post the demo here

Comment: Are you sure `persons` is really in the scope and has the value you provided?

Comment: thanks @PSL. I'm using angular bootstrap ui and it looks like there may be some issues specific with the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

JSON was the issue.

Following JSFiddle code works :

`https://jsfiddle.net/sushruthreddygade/hcpb229g/2/`

JSON Structure:

```
[
{
    "name": "First Person",
    "mutual_friends": [
        {
            "name": "Mutual Friend 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mutual Friend 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Second Person",
    "mutual_friends": [
        {
            "name": "Mutual Friend 3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mutual Friend 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

]